# An error when i create an alarms on windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

In my app, i have an alarm which is scheduled to start on today 6/25/2013(**BeginTime**)and hours later than the current time. When building i have an error "**An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll but was not handled in user code**".But i change **BeginTime** to any day in future, it works well.I follow the instructions [How to create alarms and reminders for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202965%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). How can i create an alarm with star time on today?

This is my code:
XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <ScrollViewer>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <RadioButton Content="Reminder" Name="reminderRadioButton" GroupName="ReminderOrAlarm" IsChecked="True"></RadioButton>
                    <RadioButton Content="Alarm" Name="alarmRadioButton" GroupName="ReminderOrAlarm" ></RadioButton>
                </StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="titleLabel" Text="title" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                <TextBox Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="titleTextBox" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="460" MaxLength="63"/>
                <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="contentLabel" Text="content" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                <TextBox Height="160" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="contentTextBox" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="460" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxLength="256" AcceptsReturn="True" />
                <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="beginTimeLabel" Text="begin time" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <toolkit:DatePicker x:Name="beginDatePicker" Width="220" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></toolkit:DatePicker>
                    <toolkit:TimePicker x:Name="beginTimePicker"  Width="220" HorizontalAlignment="Right"></toolkit:TimePicker>
                </StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="expirationTimeLabel" Text="expiration time" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <toolkit:DatePicker x:Name="expirationDatePicker" Width="220" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></toolkit:DatePicker>
                    <toolkit:TimePicker x:Name="expirationTimePicker" Width="220" HorizontalAlignment="Right"></toolkit:TimePicker>
                </StackPanel>
                <Grid>
                    <RadioButton Content="once" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="onceRadioButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="ScheduleInterval" IsChecked="True"/>
                    <RadioButton Content="weekly" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,70,0,0" Name="weeklyRadioButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="ScheduleInterval"/>
                    <RadioButton Content="daily" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,140,0,0" Name="dailyRadioButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="ScheduleInterval"/>
                    <RadioButton Content="monthly" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="240,0,0,0" Name="monthlyRadioButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="ScheduleInterval"/>
                    <RadioButton Content="end of month" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="240,70,0,0" Name="endOfMonthRadioButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="ScheduleInterval"/>
                    <RadioButton Content="yearly" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="240,140,0,0" Name="yearlyRadioButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="ScheduleInterval"/>
                </Grid>
                <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="param1Label" Text="context parameter 1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                <TextBox Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="param1TextBox" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="440" MaxLength="63"/>
                <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="param2Label" Text="context parameter 2" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                <TextBox Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="param2TextBox" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="440" MaxLength="63"/>

            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```

And C#:

```
private void ApplicationBarSaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String name = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        DateTime date = (DateTime)beginDatePicker.Value;
        DateTime time = (DateTime)beginTimePicker.Value;
        DateTime beginTime = date + time.TimeOfDay;
        if (beginTime < DateTime.Now)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("the begin date must be in the future.");
            return;
        }
        date = (DateTime)expirationDatePicker.Value;
        time = (DateTime)expirationTimePicker.Value;
        DateTime expirationTime = date + time.TimeOfDay;

        if (expirationTime < beginTime)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("expiration time must be after the begin time.");
            return;
        }
        RecurrenceInterval recurrence = RecurrenceInterval.None;
        if (dailyRadioButton.IsChecked == true)
        {
            recurrence = RecurrenceInterval.Daily;
        }
        else if (weeklyRadioButton.IsChecked == true)
        {
            recurrence = RecurrenceInterval.Weekly;
        }
        else if (monthlyRadioButton.IsChecked == true)
        {
            recurrence = RecurrenceInterval.Monthly;
        }
        else if (endOfMonthRadioButton.IsChecked == true)
        {
            recurrence = RecurrenceInterval.EndOfMonth;
        }
        else if (yearlyRadioButton.IsChecked == true)
        {
            recurrence = RecurrenceInterval.Yearly;
        }

        string param1Value = param1TextBox.Text;
        string param2Value = param2TextBox.Text;
        string queryString = "";
        if (param1Value != "" && param2Value != "")
        {
            queryString = "?param1=" + param1Value + "&param2=" + param2Value;
        }
        else if (param1Value != "" || param2Value != "")
        {
            queryString = (param1Value != null) ? "?param1=" + param1Value : "?param2=" + param2Value;
        }
        Uri navigationUri = new Uri("/ShowParams.xaml" + queryString, UriKind.Relative);
        if ((bool)reminderRadioButton.IsChecked)
        {
            Reminder reminder = new Reminder(name);
            reminder.Title = titleTextBox.Text;
            reminder.Content = contentTextBox.Text;
            reminder.BeginTime = beginTime;
            reminder.ExpirationTime = expirationTime;
            reminder.RecurrenceType = recurrence;
            reminder.NavigationUri = navigationUri;

            // Register the reminder with the system.
            ScheduledActionService.Add(reminder);
        }
        else
        {
            Alarm alarm = new Alarm(name);
            alarm.Content = contentTextBox.Text;
            alarm.Sound = new Uri("/Ringtones/Ring01.wma", UriKind.Relative);
            alarm.BeginTime = beginTime;
            alarm.ExpirationTime = expirationTime;
            alarm.RecurrenceType = recurrence;

            ScheduledActionService.Add(alarm);
        }
        // Navigate back to the main reminder list page.
        NavigationService.GoBack();

    }
```

Comment: You need to post the code that you're using and, more importantly, the message of the exception. You've not given nearly enough information as it is and, most likely, you've simply not set the time for the alarm to the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied your code changed nothing and it would work perfectly except for this line:

`alarm.Sound = new Uri("/Ringtones/Ring01.wma", UriKind.Relative);`

which makes it crash EVERYTIME on adding the alarm if that line is not removed (or the file is added to the phone)

Just comment it out and your code should work.