# Alarm with song from Music store

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am new to Windows Phone 8 platform and I want to develop an application for showing alarm.
In that I need to put an option for selecting the alarm sound from music store. Here I want to know how to set an alarm with song from music store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use WebClient to download the alarm sound from server

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
Uri uri = new Uri(songUrl);
client.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(OpenReadCallback2);
client.OpenReadAsync(uri);
```

In the OpenReadCallback2

```
      private void OpenReadCallback2(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[e.Result.Length];
            e.Result.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            using (var fs = File.Create("file.mp3"))
            {
                fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
```

Save stream in to a file named "file.mp3"

Now create your alarm

```
                Alarm objAlarm = ScheduledActionService.Find("samplealarm123") as Alarm;
                if (objAlarm != null)
                    ScheduledActionService.Remove("samplealarm123");
                objAlarm = new Alarm("samplealarm123");
                objAlarm.Content = "sample alarm";
                objAlarm.Sound = new Uri("/file.mp3", UriKind.Relative); ;
                objAlarm.BeginTime = dt;// datetime.now.addminutes(1);

                objAlarm.ExpirationTime = dt.AddMinutes(1);

                ScheduledActionService.Add(objAlarm);
```

This will play the song downloaded from server as Alarm tune.

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet out.

```
Alarm alarm = new Alarm(name);
alarm.Content = contentTextBox.Text;
alarm.Sound = new Uri("/Ringtones/Ring01.wma", UriKind.Relative);
alarm.BeginTime = beginTime;
alarm.ExpirationTime = expirationTime;
alarm.RecurrenceType = recurrence;

ScheduledActionService.Add(alarm);
```

For more take a look over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17300910/an-error-when-i-create-an-alarms-on-windows-phone-8)

Comment: "/Ringtones/Ring01.wma" is pointing to a location with in the bundle, right?

Comment: @PranavJDev yep exactly. Or even you can give a url link too.

Comment: I want to set a path that is from out side the bundle.

Comment: Outside from the bundle in the sense? Are you trying to give a tone directly from the web?

Comment: then you can give the url like this.

    new Uri("isostore:/MyFolder/MyFile.png", UriKind.Absolute);//give whatever the folder you saved in.

Take a look over [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402541%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for more.

Comment: I tried every thing from the link you provided but no luck. And i came into the conclusion that setting alarm tune from music library is not possible.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I got the answer and posted my answer